# Why does weight decay produce regularisation in Deep Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation, regularization

Weight decay penalizes the model to have smaller weights but how does this help in regularisation?

Any intuition on **smaller weights => simpler model**?